# Create Div with double diagonal borders

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to achieve the following lay-out:

[image: Layout Preview]

**So far** I've used skewed DIVs but I'm stuck at this result:

[image: Layout so far]

Is there a way to stop the skew at the middle and making it go back up?
Or am I aproaching this in a wrong way?

The css code I have:

```
.slanted {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.slanted:before, .slanted:after {
  content: "";
  background: white;
  height: 65px;
  transform: skewY(2deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 500;
}
.slanted:before{    
  top: -30px;    
}
.slanted:after {
  bottom: -30px;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jsbutler483/cte0bzhv/ <-- needs tidying, but gives you the effect

Comment: probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842605/how-to-make-the-bottom-of-bootstrap-navbar-meet-at-a-point where comment seemed to be giving a solution or at least good tips

Answer (score 3):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/lisucop/1/edit?html,css,output)***

Inside your main `.container` add two additional elements,
`<div class="slant-top"></div>` and `<div class="slant-bottom"></div>`
Those elements are just *holders* for `:after` and `:before`, `-top` will buld the "ears" and `-bottom` will build with those pseudos the "nose".

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;}
html, body{height:100%; margin:0;}

/* COMMONALITIES */
body{background:#322}
.container{
  position:relative;
  padding:0 24px;
}
.bg-white{background:#fff;}
.color-white{color:#fff;}
.padd-v-24{padding-top:24px; padding-bottom:24px;}
.padd-v-72{padding-top:72px; padding-bottom:72px;}


/* SLANTED BORDERS */
.slant-top:before,
.slant-top:after,
.slant-bottom:before,
.slant-bottom:after{
  content: "";
  background: white;
  height: 65px;
  top: -30px; 
  width:50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.slant-top:before,
.slant-bottom:before{    
  left: 0; 
  transform: skewY(2deg);
}
.slant-top:after,
.slant-bottom:after{
  right: 0;
  transform: skewY(-2deg);
}
.slant-bottom:before,
.slant-bottom:after{
  top:auto;
  bottom: -30px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container padd-v-24 bg-white">
  <div class="slant-top"></div>
  <h1>1 Content goes here</h1>
  <div class="slant-bottom"></div>
</div>

<div class="container padd-v-72 color-white">
  <h1>Me no slant, I has padd ;)</h1>
</div>

<div class="container padd-v-24 bg-white">
  <div class="slant-top"></div>
  <h1>2 Content goes here</h1>
  <div class="slant-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wouldn't mind using an inline svg, which has pretty good [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-html5), you could wrap it inside your absolute positioned div. The paragraph inside would have to be absolute positioned as well. Just make sure to add the [`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) and [`preserveAspectRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) attributes to the svg, this way you can define the points for a polygon as if they were percentage values.

Here is an example.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: black;
}

.slanted-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 125px;
  height: 320px;
}

.slanted, .slanted-wrapper p {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5%;
  width:100%;
  height: inherit;
}

.slanted-wrapper p {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: gray;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20%;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.slanted svg {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.slanted svg .slanted-poly {
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="slanted-wrapper">
  <div class="slanted">
    <svg width='100%' height='100%' viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <polygon class="slanted-poly" points="50 25, 100 0, 100 75, 50 100, 0 75, 0 0" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum porro ut laboriosam, quis odio eos eveniet sapiente quae deserunt? Dolore fugit quaerat iure sequi. Eveniet nisi, quidem dolor molestias est.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This was great! While I didn't use yours verbatim, the breakdown of using SVG worked perfectly for my case. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [background image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) , [linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) and [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) it is responsive and clean.

**Preview:**

[image]

**Demo:**

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box
}
body{
 margin:0;
 background: rgba(36, 39, 41, 0.14);
}
section{
 padding: 20px;
 text-align: center
}
article{
 width: 80vw;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.slanted{
  background: white;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  position: relative
}
.slanted:before,.slanted:after,
.slanted article:before,.slanted article:after{ 
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px
}
.slanted:before,.slanted:after{ 
  top: 100%;
}
.slanted article:before,.slanted article:after{ 
  bottom: 100%;
}
.slanted:before{ 
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 50%, white 51%);
}
.slanted:after{ 
  right: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 50%, white 51%);
}
.slanted article:before{ 
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 50%, white 51%);
}
.slanted article:after{ 
  right: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 50%, white 51%);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <h1>what is lorem ipsum</h1>
  </article>
</section>
<section class=slanted>
  <article>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </article>
</section>
<section>
  <article></article>
</section>
```